# How to get complete image inside the circle in Raphael js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, raphael

I am able to fill the image inside the circle. But the problem is image getting zoomed inside the circle, i want image to be less zoomed or fit into circle.

```
<div class="disp"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
  var r = Raphael("disp");

  var cir=r.circle(100, 100,33).attr({fill:"url(image.jpg)"});
// image get zoomed, how to make image fit into circle or less zoomed
```

Please help me! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do some mathematics. Don't use `attr(fill)` - create an `image`-object and fit it in your circle.
[Here](http://raphaeljs.com/image-rotation.html) is a great example of such behaviour.

BTW, you wrote **class**="disp" and `var r = Raphael("disp");` won't work - this function waits for **id**.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162132/raphael-filling-background-with-image-fillfit/18320938#18320938) you can put directly into your code, assuming you're using jQuery as well as Raphael